# Does Mind Blank provide protection from Turn Undead?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, undead

If an undead character is under the effect of a [Mind Blank](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/mindBlank.htm) spell, does the spell's effect offer protection against being forced to cower or flee from a turn-undead effect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No.** Mind blank protects against:

- mind-affecting spells and effects (which are useless against undead anyways)
- information gathering by divination spells or effects (which obviously turn undead isn't)

Turn undead isn't either. However, I suggest you look at different items of turn resistance if that is what you are after.

The spell **Life Ward** (Cl 4) from the spell compendium makes you completely immune.

Comment: That spell seems to be just what I needed. Thanks! Accepting when it becomes possible.

Comment: Not that I find fault with the answer, but it is considered good practice to wait about 24 hours before Accepting, so as to not discourage others who may have a relevant answer to add. Accepting implies the question is done.

Comment: My apologies. I will keep that in mind for the future - I guess I just got excited because I got an answer so fast.